# Meterpreter record_mic automation

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I am toying with the record_mic function on my laptop and noticed that no matter what i do i cannot capture a stream longer than 12 seconds or i get timeout errors. I thought this was a limitation of the record_mic command so i switched to soundrecorder. This also presented issues in that it seemed to save my files as folders. it would capture, but then output the "file" as a "folder" in my -l directory. Weird issue.

So my question is, how can I automate record_mic(since thats the only feature that works for recording sound), on a loop every 12 seconds so it sort of emulates 'continuous' live capture?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

record_mic -d 20
record_mic -d 20
record_mic -d 20
record_mic -d 20
record_mic -d 20

```
write this in a txt file as you need 1min=3times etc.. and copy/paste in your meterpreter ..
```

good LUCK

Comment: Hello. welcome to the community, you should use a for loop or something similar for this if possible...